# File Reader Not Setting Enum

Tags: java, file, enums

I'm currently using and `enum` to help store multiple variables inside of my code, but when I attempt to read them from my text file it doesn't seem to set the integer.

I'm bewildered and utterly confused, I can't understand why this won't work.

If any of you can tell me why, **here is my code:**

```
public static void readFile() {
    try {
        BufferedReader DesterationReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Desteration/desteration.txt/"));
        String seperator = "";

        while ((seperator = DesterationReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                String[] var3 = seperator.split(":");

                    if (var3[0].equals("Gui"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Gui.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Gui Keybind " + Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                    }

                    if (var3[0].equals("Xray"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Xray.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Xray Keybind " + var3[1]);
                    }

                    if (var3[0].equals("Fullbright"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Fullbright.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Fullbright Keybind " + var3[1]);
                    }

                    if (var3[0].equals("Wallhack"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Wallhack.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Wallhack Keybind " + var3[1]);
                    }

                    if (var3[0].equals("Sprint"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Sprint.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Sprint Keybind " + var3[1]);
                    }

                    if (var3[0].equals("Forcefield"))
                    {
                        Desteration.DesterationHacks.Forcefield.setKeybind(Integer.parseInt(var3[1]));
                        System.out.println("Setting Forcefield Keybind " + var3[1]);
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error Reading File: " + e);
                DesterationFileGenerator.editFile();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully read file.");
        System.out.println(Desteration.DesterationHacks.Gui.getKeybind());
        DesterationReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error Reading File: " + e);
    }
}
```

That's my read file and here is my setKeybind and getKeybind inside of my enum:

```
        public static void setKeybind(int i) {
        keyBind = i;
    }       
            public static int getKeybind() {
        return keyBind;
    }
```

If I read the integer directly from the `readFile()` it works fine but if I read it from the `getKeybind` it comes out as a zero.

The `Numbers` inside the file are all different, **Ex:** The GUI `Keybind` is a 98.

Here is my full enum as requested:

```
public static enum DesterationHacks {
    Gui,
    Xray,
    Fullbright,
    Wallhack,
    Sprint,
    Forcefield;

    private static boolean modState;
    private static int modMode;
    private static int keyBind;

    public static boolean getState() {
        return modState;
    }

    public static void setState(boolean flag){
        modState = flag;
    }

    public static void toggleState(){
        modState = !modState;
    }

    public static int getMode(){
        return modMode;
    }

    public static void setMode(int i){
        modMode = i;
    }

    public static int getKeybind() {
        return keyBind;
    }

    public static void setKeybind(int i) {
        keyBind = i;
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with `Enum` in the title?

Comment: Can you post full code of your enum?

Comment: What enum? What's the question?

Comment: Why are all the enum fields static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, i'm stupid. Enums shouldn't be static, or they won't form to change. Thanks for no help.

Comment: No. 'static enum' doesn't mean anything different from 'enum'. The real problem is that your enum *member variables* are all static, where they should be instance variables, one set per enum value.